# central heating comes on at night

Tags: thermostat

we have had this problem for over a year on & off, we have an ideal logic+ 30w combi boiler 8 years old, in fairness has been great , but the central heating sometimes comes on in the night (full blast) until we wake up red hot and go downstairs to find that the thermostat is set to 10c and the timer is set from 16.30 -22.30
we have tried turning the thermostat to zero and turning it off at the stat but the boiler just keeps pumping out until turned off at the boiler , as i said it doesnt do it all the time , its not the frost protection as it was 18c last night

Comment: Is the boiler controlled by the timer?

Comment: You may have the timer reversed, having it on between 22:30 and 16:30 instead of 16:30 and 22:30.

Comment: Yes it is controlled by a timer and has been since it was installed, the only recent change was to cancel a 1hrs heating slot in a morning.  The timer has a off function which didn't work in the night when we discovered that the heating was on, hence I had to turn the boiler off